# Proving that convergence of a series implies weak convergence in an inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, inner-products, weak-convergence

I'd like to prove the following:

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n = u$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle u_n, x \rangle = \langle u, x \rangle$ for any $x$ in an inner product space.

Is the following proof valid?

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n = u$ means that  $\|\sum_{n=1}^N u_n - u\| \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.

So, $|\sum_{n=1}^N \langle u_n, x \rangle - \langle u, x \rangle |$

$= | \langle \sum_{n=1}^N u_n - u, x \rangle |$, by linearity of inner products

$\le \| \sum_{n=1}^N u_n - u \| \| x \|$, by the Schwarz inequality

$\to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.

Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle u_n, x \rangle = \langle u, x \rangle$

Comment: Beside the fact that you used the same symbol $\|\cdot\|$ for real numbers and for (potentially) abstract object, it looks fine by me.

Comment: Oh thank you. I edited the first two statements after "So," to be $| \cdot |$ instead of $\| \cdot \|$.